# How to count and display number of people by date?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to count the number of users on each day and display a different icon on the calendar for each number of users. How do I implement this?

thank you very much if you can solve it

[image]

```
firebaseDatabase.getReference().child("calendar").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            if(dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() == 1){
                String key = snapshot.getKey();
                int[] date = splitDate(key);
                Calendar event_calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                event_calendar.set(date[0], date[1], date[2]);
                EventDay event1 = new EventDay(event_calendar);
                events.clear();
                calendarView.setEvents(events);
                EventDay event = new EventDay(event_calendar,R.drawable.gyeong);
                events.add(event);
                calendarView.setEvents(events);
            }
            else if(dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() == 2){
                String key = snapshot.getKey();
                int[] date = splitDate(key);
                Calendar event_calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                event_calendar.set(date[0], date[1], date[2]);
                EventDay event1 = new EventDay(event_calendar);
                events.clear();
                calendarView.setEvents(events);
                EventDay event = new EventDay(event_calendar,R.drawable.ic_baseline_boy_24);
                events.add(event);
                calendarView.setEvents(events);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
    }
});
```

Comment: 1) *Never* leave `onCancelled` empty please, as you're ignoring possible errors. At its minimum it should be `public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { throw databaseError.toException(); }`.  --- 2) What isn't working about this code? Specifically, when you set breakpoints and step through the code line by line checking all values, which is the first line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: It doesn't throw an error, but how to count the number of children within each date?

Comment: See the second part of my comment in that case? What isn't working about the code? If you set a breakpoint on the first line inside `onDataChange` and step through it, what's the first line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: The getchildcount of that code repeats the number of days, but I don't know how to count the number of registered user codes within that date.

Comment: Would that be `snapshot.getChildrenCount()`?

Comment: I solved now by overlapping  firebaseDatabase.getReference().child("calendar").child(datasnapshot.getkey)addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {  this made i can get useridcounts

Comment: Good to hear you got it working!  --- You might want to post the working solution and an explanation as a self-answer, so others can benefit from it too.